CTRL + X not working on ubuntu 22.04
ctrl + x is not working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Acer Laptop.
Suddenly stopped, must have been after an update. I've tried compressed air cleaning, upside down (gentle) shaking, reconfiguring the keyboard drivers and the console. I've checked out both the ctrl key and the x key. Ctrl + v - z both work and the x key types just fine. I've also looked at compiz and at d-conf and found  no solution. I've also looked far and wide on the Internet. Anybody here solved this problem?

A single key failure might be something physical, a multi-key failure would suggest a software issue.  Compressed air, shaking etc. would deal with something physical.  Your comment "Suddenly stopped, must have been after an update" also suggests this is a software problem, not a hardware problem.

A possible proof to preclude something physical would be to boot your system from a standalone USB, such as an initial Ubuntu 22.04 or 24.04.  If Ctrl-V works - you know it's software.

Thanks one more thing to try at least. I'll let you know if it works.
